# Allow auto scaling in Android Drawables for various densities?

Tags: android, performance, android-resources, android-memory

A lot of blogs and best practices for Android Development says

"**You don't need to supply bitmaps for every possible density, Android will scale your bitmaps (typically when they are loaded) to match the current density**."

Reference Link : https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/6eWwQvFGLV8

I tried it works well.
But i couldn't understand one thing.

For instance i created a sample app with 5 full screen images of around 1.5 MB each in a view pager.

I created heavy images for 7 inch MDPI devices like Galaxy Tab 2 and put them in "drawable-large-mdpi" folder. It was bit jerky but didn't crash and let me scroll through all the images.

Now i tried to use the app on my Nexus 7 which is almost a large HDPI device. The app crashed with "OOM error" while decoding the bitmap.

**If i move the images from large MDPI to large HDPI, it works well on both the devices with out any crash. **

**So i have two questions.**

1. Does this result incline towards, we can only put the graphics assets in the highest density drawable folder and let it scale down automatically in its range ?
2. What happens internally why it crashed for the first time ?

Answer (score 3):

1. That would be one way to do it so long as the drawables look fine when scaled. Scaling down in size *usually* is better than scaling up.  That said, there is this line:

   > Even so, when bitmaps are scaled to a density there isn't a design
   >   for, you may get artifacts such as softening of the edges.

   The reason scaling from `HDPI` to `TVDPI` works fine is because the two densities are so close. Problems with some images will start showing up between the major densities. For example, jumping from `HDPI` to `LDPI` will sure result in many artifacts as the image was simply not designed for low-resolutions.
2. It's most likely crashing with an OOM in the Nexus 7 because it's taking your large images that the device thinks are `MDPI` images and scaling them up to `TVDPI` settings. This would result in an even bigger image.

   When you put them in the HDPI folder, you're telling it to scale down to `TVDPI` so the resulting image is a less memory footprint.

   There's also the overhead that comes in to play in the actual scaling.

   The same thing will probably happen when you scale up to an XHDPI device.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you can put graphic assets into any drawable folder. If you only put resource in one density folder, the system will scale up and down to the target device densities.
2. You wanted to use a lot of memory with using those large images at the same time. Even if you use compressed image formats, when the system draws it on the screen, it will be in the memory as a bitmap. So if you keep 4-5 1200x800 pixel image in the memory at the same time it will use up that amount of memory in bitmap. That crashed your app because it ran out of the granted memory (which is very low by default android only ensure 16 mb which is usually broadened by manufacturers).

When you put the images in the hdpi, system scaled down the images, thats why there could be (not guaranteed) enough memory for the smaller images.

Solution: don't use that big images as backgrounds. Try nicely scalable images, and check out the 9-patch format: [link](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/)

Comment: I know 9 patch is a nice concept. But sometimes we can't help as you know client requirements wouldn't change. And i would not recommend using any folder as also mentioned by Deev...as the result is pretty clear...